# Change SSH home directory on SSH for Windows

Tags: windows, ssh

I have a Windows 2012 Server working inside a domain, and I have succesfully installed SSH and using Putty I can access perfectly the files in C:\Users\myusername.
My problem is that I need to access files that are in volume E:\apps and I don't know how to switch drives.  I have tried `cd /E:`and `cd /E` but I get *volume label sintax is incorrect* as an error message.

A better solution would be to start the SSH on E:\apps but I don't know how to do that either.  Is it possible this is a permissions related issue?  How would I check that?

Comment: Switching drives should be simply: `E:` You're not changing directories, you're changing volumes.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M Thanks, you're totally right, that worked.  Any ideas on how to change the default home directory when accesing via SSH?

Comment: The domain account attributes are typically specified on the Active Directory server. Open up Active Directory Users and Computers, find the user and open up properties to find the home directory.

Comment: ` I have successfully installed SSH` which SSH daemon specifically? Where did you download it?  There is a dozen different packages to install SSH on Windows some cygwin based, some other implementations.  Without knowing specifically which implementation you are using, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @zoredache I installed this one: (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/)  Do you know a more stable (better, perhaps?) implementation?

Comment: That is Microsoft's, in development version, probably the best in the long term.  But it is still pretty early in its life.

Comment: It's been just `E:` since the earliest days of MS-DOS.